# Computing a $d$-area in a $n$-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, determinant, volume

Let $n\geqslant 1$ and $\mathbb R^n$ be a $n$-dimensional space.

Let $(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$ be $d$ vectors of $\mathbb R^n$, with $d\leqslant n$.

Then $(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$ delimit a parallelogram $P$ of dimension $d$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

[image]

> What is the volume of $P$, considering $P\subseteq\mathrm{Span}(u_1,\ldots,u_d)$?

**What I tried.**

If $d=n$, the problem is easy, since

$$\mathrm{volume}(P)=\det U$$ where $M:=(u_1\vert\cdots\vert u_d)$ the matrix whose columns are $u_1,\ldots,u_d$.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem where $d<n$. Maybe we can use sub-determinants of size $d\times d$ of $U$, but I can not figure it out.

Comment: Isn’t it just the Gram-determinant of the $u_k$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That is exactly it! Thank you.